# select max value from HDF store

Tags: bash, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I would like to select the max value from some columns of a massive HDF store.

The approach which works on a smaller dataset does not scale, as it is first reading all and then picking the max value.

```
myWidth = {}
store = pd.HDFStore('store_TRAIN.h5')
for i in features_cat:
    myWidth.update({i:max(store.select_as_multiple(['myData','myFeatures','myCount']).iloc[:,i])})
    print(i)
store.close()
```

In the documentation for pd.HDFStore I could only find 'where' conditions, but nothing like 'max()'. 
Also, pandas hdfsql would only work on a pandas dataframe which is already in memory.

I would appreciate any hint.
Thanks

**Edit:**

For the ones looking for a similar answer:

I have come across HDFql, which looks promising. But it was not (yet?) available as pip package. That would be a method to consider in the future, or for a recurring task.

For this time I found it faster to parse the raw CSV file via bash command:

```
cut -d, -f2 < train_data.csv |sort -nr | head -1
```

This example assumes comma separated file, looking for max amount in 2nd column.

This took only a few seconds on a 7GB file.

Regards

Comment: If you have an answer please add it as such and do NOT edit it in your question :)

Comment: Hi, well it's more a workaround. As the initial question (how to get it from the HDF store) is not answered yet. Would prefer to leave it open as I'm interested in a better solution next time.

Comment: Oh, ok! Sorry then. I just followed the report of a bot which detected a possible answer in a question and not really into the topic I just saw an edit that added "a similar answer".

Comment: Yes probably should not have extended to an audience following the 'bash' tag, as it is only the workaround and not relevant to the question.